# Python: Compare more numbers

Tags: python, for-loop, numbers, compare

I would like to search for numbers in existing list. If is one of this numbers repeated then set variable's value to true and break for loop.

```
list = [3, 5, 3] //numbers in list
```

So if the function gets two same numbers then break for - in this case there is 3 repeated.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). You loop through your list, and either add the number to a support set, or break out the loop.

```
>>> l = [3, 5, 3]
>>> s = set()
>>> s
set([])
>>> for x in l:
...     if x not in s:
...         s.add(x)
...     else:
...         break
```

You could also take a step further and make a function out of this code, returning the first duplicated number you find (or `None` if the list doesn't contain duplicates):

```
def get_first_duplicate(l):
    s = set()
    for x in l:
        if x not in s:
            s.add(x)
        else:
            return x

get_first_duplicate([3, 5, 3])
# returns 3
```

Otherwise, if you want to get a boolean answer to the question "does this list contain duplicates?", you can return it instead of the duplicate element:

```
def has_duplicates(l):
    s = set()
    for x in l:
        if x not in s:
            s.add(x)
        else:
            return true
    return false

get_first_duplicate([3, 5, 3])
# returns True
```

---

**[senderle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577088/)** pointed out:

> there's an idiom that people sometimes use to compress this logic into a couple of lines. I don't necessarily recommend it, but it's worth knowing:

```
s = set(); has_dupe = any(x in s or s.add(x) for x in l)
```

Comment: As you may be aware, there's an idiom that people sometimes use to compress this logic into a couple of lines. I don't necessarily recommend it, but it's worth knowing: `s = set(); has_dupe = any(x in s or s.add(x) for x in lst)`

Comment: @senderle I didn't know it. I personally prefer the sparse (vs dense) version, but it's nice to know it. I'll add it to the answer; thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 4):

First, don't name your list `list`. That is a [**Python built-in**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), and using it as a variable name can give undesired side effects. Let's call it `L` instead.

You can solve your problem by comparing the list to a [**set**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) version of itself.

Edit: You want true when there **is** a repeat, not the other way around. Code edited.

```
def testlist(L):
    return sorted(set(L)) != sorted(L)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `collections.Counter()` and `any()`:

```
>>> lis=[3,5,3]
>>> c=Counter(lis)
>>> any(x>1 for x in c.values()) # True means yes some value is repeated
True
>>> lis=range(10)
>>> c=Counter(lis)
>>> any(x>1 for x in c.values()) # False means all values only appeared once
False
```

or use `sets` and match lengths:

```
In [5]: lis=[3,3,5]

In [6]: not (len(lis)==len(set(lis)))
Out[6]: True

In [7]: lis=range(10)

In [8]: not (len(lis)==len(set(lis)))
Out[8]: False
```

Comment: You return the exact opposite of what OP asks - False when there is a repeat instead of True.

Comment: That can easily be changes by appending a `not`if the OP desires, and I  explained the meaning of `True`,`False` for both cases in comments.

Comment: @Junuxx is right, and I think you should fix that. But this is a good solution if you fix that problem, because it may often be faster than sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You should never give the name `list` to a variable - `list` is a *type* in Python, and you can give yourself all kinds of problems masking built-in names like that. Give it a descriptive name, like `numbers`.

That said ... you could use a set to keep track of which numbers you've already seen:

```
def first_double(seq):
    """Return the first item in seq that appears twice."""
    found = set()
    for item in seq:
        if item in found:
            return item
            # return will terminate the function, so no need for 'break'.
        else:
            found.add(item)

numbers = [3, 5, 3]
number = first_double(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

without additional memory:

```
any(l.count(x) > 1 for x in l)
```

Comment: But slow -- O(n ** 2) instead of O(n).